# Converting opencv rectangle coordinate to yolo object coordinates for image labeling

Tags: c++, opencv, yolo, labeling

I want to create image labeling program with opencv c++ to label images for yolo object detector, but i'm struggling in converting rectangle coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) to yolo format which is "object-class x_center y_center width height". And according to the documentation x_center and y_center are center of rectangle (are not top-left corner).

I tried this code on already labeled image

```
            double centerX = (x1 + x2) / (2.0 * imageWidth);
            double centerY = (y1 + y2) / (2.0 * imageHeight);
            double width = double(abs(x2 - x1) / imageWidth);
            double height = double(abs(y2- y1) / imageHeight);
```

and get
`0 0.396759 0.278906 0.0109375 0.326852`
which is deferent from
`0 0.40703125 0.5194444444444445 0.25364583333333335 0.5851851851851851`.
How can i get it to work?

Comment: can you provide me the input?

Comment: The image dimensions are 1920x1080, selected rectangle coordinates(x1,y1,x2,y2)=(539, 253, 522, 601) and the output is 0 0.276302 0.39537 0.00885417 0.322222. But the output should be roughly 0 0.40703125 0.5194444444444445 0.25364583333333335 0.5851851851851851.

Comment: Why you divide imagewidth and image height? What is the math behind it? Why such small numbers, you dont wanna get the centers?

Comment: Center x 0.40 means 40 % of the image width, center y is % of the image height and so on. This is what yolo uses to detect where bounding box is.

Comment: So center x is the center of the selected rectangle width, relative to the image width, and center y is the center of the selected rectangle height, relative to the image height.

Comment: As a reference computation, I can refer [pybboxes](https://github.com/devrimcavusoglu/pybboxes).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the code that works:

```
Point centralPoint = Point((selectedRect.tl().x + selectedRect.br().x) / 2, (selectedRect.tl().y + selectedRect.br().y) / 2);
                centerX = centralPoint.x / imageWidth;
                centerY = centralPoint.y / imageHeight;

                rectWidth = abs(selectedRect.br().x - selectedRect.tl().x) / imageWidth;
                rectHeight = abs(selectedRect.br().y - selectedRect.tl().y) / imageHeight;
```